# How to recover unbootable Boot Camp partition

Tags: bootcamp, snow-leopard, windows

I have been using a 2008 MacBook Air, dual booted with OSX Snow Leopard and 32 bit Windows 8.1 for the past couple of years. It has been reliably booting using Refind and I have been mainly using Windows 8.1 as it is still supported and can use the latest browsers, Office 365 etc. It is also just about usable on this low end Core 2 Duo, 2GB RAM machine.

Yesterday, I had a problem with a USB stick which had lost its FAT32 and was recognised as RAW. In trying to fix it, I seem to have nuked the Boot Camp Partition too, or it could be a coincidence.

When I run `diskutil list`I get the following output:

```
> #:                              TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:            GUID_partition_scheme                        *126.7 GB   disk0
   1:                              EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                        Apple_HFS Mac OS                  63.0 GB    disk0s2
   3: 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-65656445                         262.1 MB   disk0s3
   4: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D847                         60.6 GB    disk0s4
   5:                            Linux Swap                    2.6 GB     disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                             TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:           Apple_partition_scheme                        *126.0 GB   disk1
   1:              Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk1s1
   2:                        Apple_HFS                     126.0 GB   disk1s2
```

Output from `sudo gpt -r show disk0`:

```
  gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         MBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34          6         
       40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  123046872      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
123456512       1024         
123457536     512000      3  GPT part - 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649
123969536  118374400      4  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
242343936    5117952      5  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
247461888       2015         
247463903         32         Sec GPT table
247463935          1         Sec GPT header
```

Output from `sudo pdisk -lr /dev/disk1`

```
    Partition map (with 512 byte blocks) on '/dev/disk1'
 #:                type name          length   base      ( size )
 1: Apple_partition_map Apple             63 @ 1        
 2:           Apple_HFS disk image 246093680 @ 64        (117.3G)

Device block size=512, Number of Blocks=246093744 (117.3G)
DeviceType=0x0, DeviceId=0x0
```

It looks as if the (working) Mac partition is partition 2 while the nuked Boot Camp Partition is partition 4. It still has a Linux Swap partition from a previous experiment with using Ubuntu. One strange result is it looks like there are two disks but there is just one 128GB SSD.

Any advice would be useful here. I have installed GDisk but I normally make matters worse when I try to use it unless I follow detailed advice.
Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Now to disk1: I can google-trace the volume name to C.G.Rapley (climatologist & fellow of the UCL)  - maybe the MBA was in Antarctica and this ancient partition scheme came to light after unfreezing it back in the UK. Then the GPT is just some kind of imprint on the Apple partition scheme. Please check the partition table content of disk1 with `sudo pdisk -lr /dev/disk1` and add it to your question.

Comment: cgrapley/d(onald)trump are just disk images! I'm not sure with the latter one - he may be real...

Comment: I cloned the drive from an old Mac many years ago, can't remember where it came from, must have been UCL!

Comment: The GPT looks like a legit (old-fashioned) dual-boot OS X/Linux partition scheme - with disk0s3: GRUB boot disk0s4: Linux native disk0s5: Linux Swap.

Comment: "...In trying to fix it, I seem to have nuked the Boot Camp Partition too..." Under certain circumstances disk0s4 might be a Windows partition. But then Bootcamp installation wasn't properly done in the past or you just did some wild cloning. Please check your Terminal history (simply enter `history`) and extract all disk related commands (diskutil/gpt/gdisk etc.) entered to fix the thumb drive and add them to your question.

Comment: Unfortunately the USB fixing took place in Windows and I can't access it at the moment. The SSD was originally cloned onto a clean, new SSD using Carbon Copy Cloner. I then set up Windows partition using Boot Camp.

Comment: I am sure that partition 4 is the Windows partition, I can tell by the size of it and from the time I have spent trying to stay within 60GB!

Comment: I don't think you can "fix" a thumb drive in Windows (booted from this disk0/disk0s*) and modify the boot disk partition scheme at the same time (accidentially). At least in OS X/macOS it doesn't work (maybe with gdisk and **no immediate** write to gpt table & subsequent reboot - I never tested this though).

Comment: It could be a coincidence.

Comment: Then boot to some external boot drive (or start the MBA in target disk mode and attach it to another Mac) and modify the gpt: 0: get device number X of 126.7 GB SSD with `diskutil list` 1. Unmount volumes/disk diskXsY/diskX 2. Remove diskXs4 `sudo gpt remove -i 4 /dev/diskX` 2.5 Unmount volumes/disk diskXsY/diskX 3. Add the now free space with `sudo gpt add -i 4 -b 123969536 -s 118374400 -t EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 /dev/diskX`.

Comment: Before doing this check the content of disk0s4 with `sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s4 of=~/Desktop/superblock bs=512 count=1` whether it is a NTFS superblock: apple.stackexchange.com/a/229447/93229 (Don't modify anything according to my answer there though; it's just important to detect the NTFS string at block 0!)

Comment: None of the partitioning posted in this question is seen by Windows. Macs in 2008 used the BIOS boot method for Windows which means Windows reads the MBR partition table. The contents of the MBR partition table can be print out by using the command `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`.

Comment: I would also warn that you can remove a partition from the GUID partition table (GPT) with `sudo gpt remove ...`. However,  you will not be able to add the partition back in with `sudo gpt add ...`, if the partition overlaps a partition defined in the MBR partition table.

Comment: As the partition table is such a mess, I have decided to clone my Mac partition onto an external drive, wipe disk and clone it back on. I will then reinstall a fresh Windows 8.1 partition using Boot Camp and avoid doing anything with Grub or Linux on this machine. I have plenty of other Linux boxes to play with! Thank you for all the help and advice.